# iOS UICollectionView select only part of Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, segue

I hope someone could point me out on the below question please.

I'm working with storyboard and created a UICollectionView with the cell designed including a header (UIView) inside which there is a UIButton. And below the header (still inside the Cell i include a UIImage).

Now i have added a second UIView which shows the detail of current cell when selected using a segue with identifier "showDetail"

The views screenshot are available in the image below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4peU.jpg

Now in my UICollectionViewController Class (first view) i added the following code :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        // Custom code to get some data to be displayed on second view
        // then display the second view
    }
}
```

Now all works fine. I can display the second view properly.

The only thing i want is NOT to display the second view when the header (UIView) of the cell is touched. I can see that if i touch the UIButton inside it does not fire up the segue and doesn't show the second view.
Now if i either click the"header" or the UIImage below it fires up the Segue and shows the second view.

I would like the segue to fireup only when the UIImage is touched.

I have tried some approaches :

- Trying to check the "sender" object wether it's the UIView or the CustomCell but it's always the Custom Cell that comes up
- Trying to define a Custom UIView Class for the "header" and adding some "Gesture handling" but even that the segue get fired up.

Any tips/help would be awesome please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the segue to fireup only when the UIImage is touched.

In the source view controller, you can implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and return NO if you don’t want this segue triggered on a particular occasion. This assumes that you have a way to detect, after the fact, that the segue is being wrongly triggered.

But really, it would be easier if you unhooked the segue in Interface Builder and only fired it up at the right moments. Do your own gesture recognition, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` only when it should be performed. You can put the UIImage in a UIImageView, turn on user interaction for that image view, give that image view a tap gesture recognizer, and away you go. (Actually you can set *that* up in Interface Builder, having the segue emanate from the image view's tap gesture recognizer.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried to add a Gesture recognition on the UiIMageView (for single tap) but it seems it doesn't take it into account . I've made sure to yes userInteractionnEnabled=YES

Comment: Also note that adding the Gesture Recognition to the Custom UICollectionViewCell works fine...But not on it's UiImageView

Comment: I finally managed to make it work your way. Just need to make sure The UIImageView was interactive and parent also thanks !!!